# Average of multiple elements from pairwise averages

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, means

There are many kinds of averages, like the [arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) and the [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean), which are defined for pairs of (positive) real numbers rather than on arbitrary multisets of (positive) reals. Is there a canonical process for converting these to multiset functions?

I'm not sure what is the best definition to use here for an average. At a minimum it would require that the function is *symmetric* in all its arguments, *homogeneous* in the sense that multiplying all elements by $k$ should increase the average by a factor of $k$, *increasing* in all of its arguments, and yields a value between the minimum and the maximum of its arguments. I also expect* that if the average of $A$ equals the average of $B$ then they also equal the average of $A\uplus B$ (where $A\uplus B$ is the union of $A$ and $B$ with multiplicity, usually called the [multiset sum](https://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets#Multiset_sum) I think). I'm open to a narrower/less-inclusive definition if it makes the answer work.

* In general it's hard to ensure that the whole is the sum of the parts, so to speak; compare the [consistency criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_criterion) in social choice theory. If you have a different idea of how to express that the new method is 'essentially' the same as the old, go ahead and use it.

Comment: See [Kolmogorov–Nagumo average](https://www.quora.com/Information-Theory/What-is-the-Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Nagumo-average). Basically $$KNM=g^{-1}(E(g(X)))$$ where $X$ is uniformly distributed over your multi-set and $g$ is a continuous strictly monotone function.

Comment: @A.S.: How would I find the function $g$ for, say, the arithmetic-geometric mean? I can't even prove that such a function exists.

Comment: I don't know enough about AG mean/its properties/uses to comment. In the least I'd try to see what do you get if you apply it to two sets of two numbers and then the pair of results and see if it's independent of the way you break up the elements.

Comment: @A.S. Good point -- it is not independent of order: agm(agm(1,2),agm(3,4)) = 2.3595... > 2.3593... = agm(agm(1,3),agm(2,4)).